# Google Analytics Site Speed Page Timings Distribution buckets

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, buckets

I am creating a script in PHP to retrieve the information, via Google Analytics V4 API, that appears in the Google Analytics tab:

> Behavior -> Site Speed -> Site Speed Page Timings -> Distribution

[image: Google Analytics Page Timings Distribution]

I cannot figure out how to obtain this data in histogram form (Page load time bucket per page load sample) with PHP code.

I was expecting that the `ga:pageLoadTime` metric had a dimension that would allow me to define the bucket intervals as a histogram.... but it does not seem to exist.

I have been able to obtain the distribution metrics for the sessions count as seen in the screen:

> Audience -> Behaviour -> Frequency & Recency

[image: Google Analytics Frequency & Recency]

**Note:** I followed the example indicated in the page: [Google Analytics API v4: Histogram Buckets](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2017/07/27/google-analytics-api-v4-histogram-buckets/)

For the metric `ga:sessions` I can use the dimension `ga:sessionCount` so I get what the screen shows.

**Current PHP code:**

```
$VIEW_ID ="xxxxxx";

// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2018-04-05");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2018-04-07");

// Create the Metrics object.
$loadTime = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$loadTime->setExpression("ga:pageLoadTime");
$loadTime->setAlias("loadTime");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setMetrics(array($loadTime));

//This next parameter without a dimension is useless!
//$request->setFiltersExpression("ga:pageLoadTime>40000");

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

**Ideally I would want to do something like this but it does not work:**

```
// Create the Dimensions object.
$buckets = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$buckets->setName("ga:pageLoadSample");
$buckets->setHistogramBuckets(array(1,8,100,201));

// Create the Ordering.
$ordering = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_OrderBy();
$ordering->setOrderType("HISTOGRAM_BUCKET");
$ordering->setFieldName("ga:pageLoadSample");

$request->setDimensions(array($buckets));
$request->setOrderBys($ordering);
```

I also accept suggestions for alternatives to the API!

Comment: You have done well to describe what you are trying to achieve but you haven't actually posted any code showing what you have done.   A lot of these reports are internal reports and there is no way to really get the exact same information out using the API your going to have to do a lot of the processing on your own.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for the comment. I don't mind doing the processing but right now I don't even see what the path could be. I have attached the sample code above for review.